# Cleaning up controllers to speed up application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

So in my app I have notifications and different record counts that are used in the overall layout, and are therefore needed on every page.

Currently in my application_controller I have a lot of things like such:

```
@status_al = Status.find_by_name("Alive")
@status_de = Status.find_by_name("Dead")
@status_sus = Status.find_by_name("Suspended")
@status_hid = Status.find_by_name("Hidden")
@status_arc = Status.find_by_name("Archived")
@balloon_active = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status_id => @status_al.id )
@balloon_dependent = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status_id => @status_de.id )
@balloon_upcoming = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status_id => @status_sus.id )
@balloon_deferred = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status_id => @status_hid.id )
@balloon_complete = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :status_id => @status_arc.id )
```

..
Thats really just a small piece, I have at least double this with similar calls. The issue is I need these numbers pretty much on every page, but I feel like I'm htting the DB wayyyy too many times here.

Any ideas for a better implementation?

Comment: It would be great if you would accept one of our answers if they addressed your question. Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry about that, was still in the process of implementing the changes - answer accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Scopes

First off, you should move many of these into `scopes`, which will allow you to use them in far more flexible ways, such as chaining queries using ActiveRecord. See http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html.

#### Indexes

Second, if you're doing all these queries anyway, make sure you **index** your database to, for example, find `Status` quickly by name. A sample migration to accomplish the first index:

```
add_index :status (or the name of your Status controller), :name
```

#### Session

If the data you need here is not critical, i.e. you don't need to rely on it to further calculations or database updates, you could consider storing some of this data in the user's session. If you do so, you can simply read whatever you need from the session in the future instead of hitting your db on every page load.

If this data is critical and/or it must be updated to the second, then avoid this option.

#### Counter Caching

If you need certain record counts on a regular basis, consider setting up a `counter_cache`. Basically, in your models, you do the following:

```
Parent.rb
has_many :children

Child.rb
belongs_to :parent, :counter_cache => true
```

Ensure your `parent` table has a field called `child_count` and Rails will update this field for you on every child's creation/deletion. If you use counter_caching, you will avoid hitting the database to get the counts.

**Note:** Using counter_caching will result in a *slightly* longer create and destroy action, but if you are using these counts often, it's usually worth going with counter_cache.

Answer (score 2):

You should only need 1 database query for this, something like:

```
@posts = Post.where(:user_id => current_user.id).includes(:status)
```

Then use Enumerable#group_by to collect the posts into the different categories:

```
posts_by_status = @posts.group_by do {|post| post.status.name }
```

which will give you a hash:

```
{'Alive' => [...], 'Dead' => [...]}
```

etc.

Comment: you're correct that it'll only take one query to resolve the OP's issue on each page view, but the OP is also trying to avoid repeating this query every time a user selects any page on the site. For that ultimate lightness on the DB, the OP needs to look into caching and/or using the session.

Comment: Good point. The OP should read up on the various forms of caching available in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: Hey Andy, I'm not sure I understand how I can use the group_by here? How can I specify the type of status to group by?